# Interpolate between two dynamic dates VBA

Tags: excel, vba, interpolation

We have a file that is updated every week and its structure is as follows:

```
      ID            Code    Days  Yield
KZW1KM093436    NTK273_1343 4    2.1781
KZW1KD913708    NTK091_1370 11   2.1683
KZK1KY011222    MKM012_0122 17   2.1602
KZW1KM063603    NTK182_1360 32   2.1419
KZW1KM093477    NTK273_1347 32   2.1419
KZW1KD913740    NTK091_1374 39   2.1342
KZW1KM063629    NTK182_1362 46   2.1269
KZW1KM093501    NTK273_1350 53   2.1202
```

I have the following static data points (Days):

```
28
91
182
273
364
730
1825
2555
3640
```

I'd like to get interpolated values for these static days as the file gets updates (basically, every week). When the file gets updated, the structure of the data also changes (sorted by `Days`). If the value in `Days` column in the data is equal to any of the values in my `Static` data, then I'd like to take the corresponding value from `Yield`. Otherwise, I'd like to take the closest upper and lower values from `Days` and get interpolated `Yield`.

So far I was able to add another column with my `Static` values next to `Yield` column:

```
Sub io()

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim maxval As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    c = 5

    Cells(4, c) = 28
    Cells(5, c) = 91
    Cells(6, c) = 182
    Cells(7, c) = 273
    Cells(8, c) = 364
    Cells(9, c) = 730
    Cells(10, c) = 1825
    Cells(11, c) = 2555
    Cells(12, c) = 3640

    maxval = Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row, 3).Value
    Range("B1") = maxval

    r = 4

    Do Until Cells(r, 3) = "" Or Cells(r, 5) = ""
        If Cells(r, 3) > Cells(r, 5) Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 4)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Else
        If Cells(r, 5) > Cells(r, 3) Then Cells(r, 5).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
        r = r + 1
    Loop
```

And the structure of the data became:

```
      ID            Code    Days  Yield Static
KZW1KM093436    NTK273_1343 4    2.1781
KZW1KD913708    NTK091_1370 11   2.1683
KZK1KY011222    MKM012_0122 17   2.1602
                                         28
KZW1KM063603    NTK182_1360 32   2.1419
KZW1KM093477    NTK273_1347 32   2.1419
KZW1KD913740    NTK091_1374 39   2.1342
KZW1KM063629    NTK182_1362 46   2.1269
KZW1KM093501    NTK273_1350 53   2.1202
```

Now I want to delete all the redundant rows and add another column that uses interpolation, but can't proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you identify a redundant row?  what are you interpolating?

Comment: In this particular case the first 2 and the last 4 rows are redundant and I'm interpolating `Yield`